# Matching an expression including arbitrary lines with regex in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

In a text file opened with Vim, I'm trying to match the occurrence of two strings, DRIVER_ACTIVITY and DriverGroup, with an arbitrary amount of lines in between:

```
2013-07-01 05:06:23,801 DRIVER_ACTIVITY
2013-07-01 05:06:23,804 text
2013-07-01 05:06:23,804 more text
2013-07-01 05:06:23,805 DriverGroup
```

using:

```
/DRIVER_ACTIVITY(.*)DriverGroup/s  
/DRIVER_ACTIVITY((.|\n|\r)*)DriverGroup  
/\vDRIVER_ACTIVITY((.|\n|\r)*)DriverGroup  
/DRIVER_ACTIVITY\[\S\s\]*DriverGroup
```

Nothing matches. How do I match all the lines/new lines?

Comment: don't use vim, but maybe inline multiline `(?s)`? `/(?s)DRIVER_ACTIVITY(.*?)DriverGroup`

Comment: Your third attempt (starting with `\v`) matches for me.

Comment: For me the third attempt contains trailing whitespaces. Without them it matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see the problem. In this sample file, the third try matches, as does Ingo Karkat's and Explosion Pills' suggestions. The reason I didn't succeed is because all these seem to be greedy. That's why none of these matches in "the big file", 'cause it's greedy and keeps on looking, not returning a match in several seconds, though the marker is located on the same line where the first match should appear. So it actually matches but my patience is the problem :)

I made it non greedy and it worked:
/DRIVER_ACTIVITY_.{-}DriverGroup

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the more common `(...)` for grouping, you need to include the `\v` atom to switch Vim's regular expression syntax to "very magic"; else, it's `\(...\)`. But for your case, Vim has a special atom that matches arbitrary characters *including newlines*: `\_.`, like this:

```
/DRIVER_ACTIVITY\_.*DriverGroup
```

There's no way around learning Vim's different regular expression dialect; see `:help pattern`.

Answer (score 2):

[The `\_s` construct searches spaces including newlines](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_across_multiple_lines)

```
/DRIVER_ACTIVITY\(\_s\|.\)*DriverGroup
```