# Vim Regex Capture Groups [bau -> byau : ceu -> cyeu]

Tags: regex, vim, capturing-group, regex-group

I have a list of words:

```
bau
ceu
diu
fou
gau
```

I want to turn that list into:

```
byau
cyeu
dyiu
fyou
gyau
```

I unsuccessfully tried the command:

```
:%s/(\w)(\w\w)/\1y\2/g
```

Given that this doesn't work, what do I have to change to make the regex capture groups work in Vim?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matching an expression including arbitrary lines with regex in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471929/matching-an-expression-including-arbitrary-lines-with-regex-in-vim) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627893/vim-match-errors-out-with-regular-expression-ffelrf

Comment: It's a little bit off-topic so I put it here as a comment but… I'd do `:%norm ay<CR>`.

Comment: In your case (if it's exactly like described), it's an option to: move to 2nd column with `l`, enter Visual Block mode with `Ctrl+v`, mark whole column with `Shift+g` followed by `l`, then enter Insert mode with `Shift+i`and input 'y'. 7 keystrokes including finishing `Esc` to exit Insert mode. Not posting as an answer because it's not really about capture groups (which is what I searched for when I found this). :-)

Answer (score 332, accepted):

One way to fix this is by ensuring the pattern is enclosed by *escaped* parentheses:

```
:%s/\(\w\)\(\w\w\)/\1y\2/g
```

Slightly shorter (and more *magic*-al) is to use `\v`, meaning that in the pattern after it all ASCII characters except `'0'-'9'`, `'a'-'z'`, `'A'-'Z'` and `'_'` have a special meaning:

```
:%s/\v(\w)(\w\w)/\1y\2/g
```

#### See:

- [`:help \(`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%28)
- [`:help \v`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Cv)

Answer (score 70):

You can also use this pattern which is shorter:

```
:%s/^./&y
```

- `%s` applies the pattern to the whole file.
- `^.` matches the first character of the line.
- `&y` adds the `y` after the pattern.

Comment: Its amazing how after more than 10 years and a quite a bit of expertise in vim, I still learn new tricks like using "&" to add rather than to substitute. thanks

Comment: @Kiteloopdesign `&` is actually just another name for `\0`, which is the capture group containing the entire sequence that was matched.

Answer (score 57):

If you don't want to escape the capturing groups with backslashes (this is what you've missed), prepend `\v` to turn Vim's regular expression engine into *very magic* mode:

```
:%s/\v(\w)(\w\w)/\1y\2/g
```

Comment: Ingo, sorry for the placing a question in the wrong place: This works find in `:exmode`; is there a way to do it in gvim find/replace dialogue box?

Comment: @JJoao: No, the find/replace box is for literal search and replacement only. You shouldn't be using that, anyway; it's just training wheels for Notepad users.

Comment: Ingo, thank you (it is not for me: I am happy with exmode, but for linguists colaborators in a dictionary project): it almost work - with `\v...` regexp work find; in the replacement string, `&` works but `\ ` are protected (`\1\r` are lost)

Comment: @JJoao: Yes, that's what I found out while playing with it, too. I'm still skeptical whether using Vim without Ex mode is a good idea, but you could easily build your own search-and-replace dialog (internally powered by `:s`) via `inputdialog()` and a bit of Vimscript.

Comment: Ingo: Thank you again; I agree with your skeptical opinion. Inputdialg+:s+vimscript is probably the way gvim's find replace is built. For me `\1 \r ` treatment is a gvim bug. I will try to post it in some vim specific list. In the meanwhile I will try my one vimscript-inputdialog.

Answer (score 17):

You also have to escape the Grouping paranthesis:

```
:%s/\(\w\)\(\w\w\)/\1y\2/g
```

That does the trick.

Comment: Coming from Sublime Text 3, this is horrible. Why is the syntax like this? It doesn't make sense to escape characters that aren't literal, normal text.

Comment: @Unknow0059 the parenthesis in this case aren't literal text. they are meta characters that delimit the groups to save for the replace expression. placing a non-escaped paren in an expression will match the literal character, as one would expect (this was what tripped up the OP).

Comment: I'm a regular vim user and I also think this is terrible. @Unknow0059

Comment: @Unknow0059 because vim is older than the normal regex syntax that we all use nowadays. Most people that use vim just use the `\v` version described in other answers though, rather than escape every little thing in their regex

Answer (score 7):

In `Vim`, on a ***selection***, the following

```bash
:'<,'>s/^\(\w\+ - \w\+\).*/\1/
```

or

```bash
:'<,'>s/\v^(\w+ - \w+).*/\1/
```

parses

`Space - Commercial - Boeing`

to

`Space - Commercial`

Similarly,

`apple - banana - cake - donuts - eggs`

is parsed to

`apple - banana`

**Explanation**

- `^` : match start of line
- `\`-escape `(`, `+`, `)` per the first regex (accepted answer) -- or prepend with `\v` (@ingo-karkat's answer)
- `\w\+` finds a word (`\w` will find the first *character*): in this example, I search for a word followed by `-` followed by another word)
- `.*` after the capturing group is needed to find / match / exclude the remaining text

---

**Addendum.**  This is a bit off topic, but I would suggest that Vim is not well-suited for the execution of more complex regex expressions / captures.  [I am doing something similar to the following, which is how I found this thread.]

In those instances, it is likely better to dump the lines to a text file and edit it "in place"

`sed -i ...`

or in a redirect

`sed ... > out.txt`

In a terminal (or BASH script, ...):

```bash
echo 'Space Sciences - Private Industry - Boeing' | sed -r 's/^((\w+ ){1,2}- (\w+ ){1,2}).*/\1/'

Space Sciences - Private Industry 

cat in.txt

Space Sciences - Private Industry - Boeing

sed -r 's/^((\w+ ){1,2}- (\w+ ){1,2}).*/\1/' ~/in.txt > ~/out.txt

cat ~/out.txt 

Space Sciences - Private Industry

## Caution: if you forget the > redirect, you'll edit your source.
## Subsequent > redirects also overwrite the output; use >> to append
## subsequent iterations to the output (preserving the previous output).
 
## To edit "in place" (`-i` argument/flag):

sed -i -r 's/^((\w+ ){1,2}- (\w+ ){1,2}).*/\1/' ~/in.txt

cat in.txt

Space Sciences - Private Industry
```

`sed -r 's/^((\w+ ){1,2}- (\w+ ){1,2}).*/\1/'`

(note the `{1,2}`) allows the flexibility of finding `{x,y}` repetitions of a word(s) -- see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html .

Here, since my phrases are separated by `-`, I can simply tweak those parameters to get what I want.