# Why isn't vim replacing my text the way I expect?

Tags: regex, vim

I have this string in my document:

```
subject.reset();
```

I am running this regex:

```
:%s/reset\(\)/doStuff\(\)/g
```

And the result looks like this:

```
subject.doStuff()();
```

Where did that extra parenthesis pair come from?  I wanted it to look like this:

```
subject.doStuff();
```

How do I do that search and replace in vim?

Comment: You don't need to escape `()` inside vim. Try  `:%s/reset()/doStuff()/g`

Comment: Well, you need to escape them if your using them as a capture group, however, you're not.

Comment: @l'L'l so in vim you escape parens to mark them as capture groups?  That's the opposite of most regex engines I've used.  Very strange.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit odd I'll agree... `sed` works much the same way actually, which is similar to vim's regex engine.

Comment: use `\v` for regex behavior similar to other engines.. like this `:%s/\vreset\(\)/doStuff\(\)/g` to know more, check out `:h \v`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape `()` inside vim. Try

```
:%s/reset()/doStuff()/g
```

or

```
:%s/reset/doStuff/g
```

`\(` or `\)` denotes capturing group inside `vim`. See **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902089/vim-regex-capture-groups)** about capturing group.

**In your example**

`reset\(\)` actually means that you are replacing `reset` and a capturing group(*which is empty and it does not really contain the parenthesis you intended*). So, basically you are replacing only `reset` with `doStuff()`..

```
subject.doStuff()();
         ^^      ^^
         ||    (was already here after reset and not replaced)
     reset is replaced with do Stuff()
```

The parenthesis after `reset` is still there

Comment: I understand now what I did wrong, but why did it put `()()` in the replace?

Comment: @DanielKaplan `reset\(\)` actually means that you are replacing `reset` and a capturing group(_which is empty and it does not really contain the parenthesis you intended_). So it is basically you are replacing only `reset` with `doStuff()`.. the parenthesis after `reset` is still there