# vim syntax match using regex and non-greedy modifier

Tags: regex, vim, syntax, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am trying to create a custom syntax that has a structure similar to the following

```
Title String:
{
   ...,
   ...,
   ...
}

Title String2:
{
   ...,
   {
      ...,
      ...,
      ...
   }
   ...,
   ...,
   ...
}
```

I have been able to write `syn match` and `syn region` statements that detect everything within the `{ ... }` regions, however I have not been able to come up with one that will match the Title Strings.

Here is my region statement:

```
syn region dbgMessage start="{" end="}" contains=ALLBUT,dbgMessageHeader
```

I attempted to add something like this to detect the Title Strings, which I want to be everything/anything up to but not including the opening bracket.

```
syn match dbgMessageHeader "\v.\{-}\ze(\{)"
```

My reasoning:

- `.\{-}` should consume every character and be non greedy
- `\ze(\{)` should look ahead for an opening bracket and stop when it finds one

A bonus challenge is that it would be great if this syntax could correctly detect everything if I get the code in a flattened state, ex:

```
Title String: { ..., ..., ... }
Title String2: { ..., { ..., ..., ... } ..., ..., ... }
```

Again, my current implementation can correctly match everything inside the brackets in both flat and formatted states, so it would be great if I could figure something out that would also match the title strings in both cases.

See something that I'm missing?

Comment: This syntax looks suspiciously like JSON. Have you tried using that?

Comment: How deep can it nest?

Comment: @Laurel Theoretically as deep as it needs to. In practice I've only seen 4 levels max.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with Vim's regex syntax, but this regex will work for most Perl-based flavors (with the `s` modifier):

```
\s([^\s]+):.*?\{
```

To translate that into Vim, it should be (I think):

```
\s\([^\s]\+\):\_.\{-}{
```

Note that I am using `\_.` instead of `.` to make it act like the `s` modifier.

Also note that "[very magic mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19902166/6083675)" (whatever that is) will probably mess this up.

---

It's not easy (if possible) to get the "flat version", since Vim only supports DFA matching.

Comment: Is this still valid even though the TitleString isnt recursive? It only appears at the beginning of a top-level `{ ... }` block

Comment: @wKavey It might be possible... Does it happen before every `{`?

Comment: It happens before every top level one (as shown in the question)

Comment: @wKavey OK, edited. See if this works; I'm not familiar with Vim regexes.

Comment: Thanks, `.*?` didn't work in vim, I tried it before googling, `.\{-}` did work, though.