# Using ex editor to increment a number following a pattern in a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, ex

Am aware of how to use the `ex` editor in syntaxes like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40169300/5291015) to do minor editing of files in place.

For example, as mentioned in the answer, assuming I have a file content as below:-

```
$ cat input-file
patternGoingDown
foo
bar
foo
bar
```

Running a command using `ex`, like

```
$ printf "%s\n" '/patternGoingDown' 'd' '/foo' 'n' 'put' 'wq' | ex file
$ cat file
foo
bar
foo
patternGoingDown
bar
```

will move the pattern `patternGoingDown` after the second occurrence of `foo`. My requirement is to adopt a similar logic to increment a number after a pattern.

Example:-

```
$ cat input-file
The number is now number(60)
```

Is it possible to use the `ex` editor to increment the number from `60` to `61`like

```
$ cat input-file
The number is now number(61)
```

Though there is a [ex-editor](http://www.csb.yale.edu/userguides/wordprocess/vi-summary.html) help page available, I can't figure out how to

1. Parse the next character after search pattern, `number` in this case
2. Increment to `61` which I can normally do via `Ctrl+A` when using `vi` editor.

I am aware there are other tools for this job, but I particularly need to use `ex` editor in the syntax I have mentioned.

Comment: `ex` is properly symlinked is `vim`. And FYI, `<C-a>` is not available in `vi`. You can do something like `vim a.txt +'g/hello/norm '$'\001''|ZZ'` with vim.

Comment: @andlrc : You mean to say a bunch of ex commands cannot be run similar to the example I gave before for my new use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky because Vim is not really suited to this. [Awk is](//vi.stackexchange.com/a/7275), but POSIX
Awk does not do in place, so you have to use both:

```
ex -sc '%!awk "\
{\
  match(\$0, /[[:digit:]]+/)\
  j = substr(\$0, RSTART, RLENGTH)\
  sub(j, ++j)\
}\
1\
"' -cx file
```

Comment: `but POSIX Awk does not do in place` This can be solved with: `awk ... file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file`

Comment: I was looking for a more straight forward way to do this like the example I gave. :(

Comment: @StevenPenny : I will accept this answer in a few minutes, since  I guess it's not possible to simulate ctrl A action through commands on the file.

Comment: @andlrc I think you know that is not a good solution. More robust would be using `mktemp`

Comment: @StevenPenny Well, that depends if it a script or interactive.